# Updating React and other npm modules

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-tsx

I just started working on a React project. Most of the modules where not updated for ~5 years. Because I want to use React-hooks I need to update React at least to 16.8.0.

First I tried to update all the dependencies we have to the latest version at once. This failed due to a lot of breaking changes.

Second I tried to update only React to 16.8.0. There I got the error `.../node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts (33,47): Cannot find name 'T'.`
prop-types is not a direct dependency of my project. Therefore I don't understand how I'm supposed to fix it.

Would you recomend to update each dependency seperatly or is it nessecary to update multiple at once? And is it easier to update to update directly to the latest version or should i do multiple steps?

Comment: Can you try with 
`npm install react@latest react-dom@latest` or instead latest - you specific version.
If you got error, you can force the installation with --force flag
eg: npm install react@latest --force

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe i did not explain well enouth. I can update react but after the update I can't start the project. I get the same error when I try to update to lastest as i get when I update to 16.8.0 (`.../node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts (33,47): Cannot find name 'T'.`)